# Rotating a camera to face a plane in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I have a problem in Three.js that I just can't solve.
The input coordinates are points in a 3d space that are all in one plane. The plane is tilted in the 3d space (in the image, the grey lines are only supposed to show how it could be tilted). I need to move the camera so that it is facing the middle of that object from the top down view (in the picture, the camera is red).
[image: The problem]

The desired output is the second image. Basically, it should represent the obejct as if it was in 2d. I know this is a loaded question, but even a small lead on how to do some part of the problem would be really helpful. If anyone needs more information, I'll be happy to share.
[image: Desired output]
Thanks everyone for the help.
Best regards,
Thomas

Comment: Posting full code will make it easier to figure out.  Start by checking out https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.lookAt and target the current camera position

Comment: 1. Compute the centroid of all input points. 2. Displace the centroid out of the plane with direction of the plane normal vector. 3 Use the displaced point as Camera position. 4. Use the negative of plane normal as lookAt direction. The up vector is tricky as you have infinite choices. I think you can find the Up vector from the input if you have LINES as well as points as input.

Comment: @MauricioCeleLopezBelon The `up` vector could be the perpendicular of the bottom line bisecting the plane.

Comment: Mauricios comment is right and it works! Thanks very much for the help.